# Find smallest sum of products without changing the order

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have two unequal length arrays:

```
A = np.array([7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
B = np.array([37.97, 34.45, 32.41, 32.17, 35.48, 35.91, 33.81, 32.23, 33.46,
       35.35, 33.03, 37.36, 32.18, 29.29, 30.23, 30.94, 34.26, 31.74,
       29.24, 25.93, 29.26, 33.64, 33.28])
```

I need to choose 7 numbers from B so that the dot product with A is smallest, or `min(7x1 + 6x2 + 5x3 +...+2x6 + x7)`. The order of both arrays must not be changed, for example if `x1 = 32.41 (index 2)`, `x2` must not be the previous indexes.

The length of A and B are in fact larger than in the example, so I'm searching for some efficient algorithm instead of brute-force.Any ideas?

EDIT: By not changing the order, I mean if I choose element at index 2, the next one could be index 5 or 10, but not at index 0 or 1. They dont need to be consecutive like index 2,3,4,5....

**UPDATE ANSWER:**
So this is what I have done so far based on @templatetypedef and @Damien answers:

```
def min_dot_product(A,B,m,n):
    P = np.zeros((n,m))
    A_ = np.zeros((n,m))
    B_ = np.zeros((n,m))
    #P[0,0] = 0 
    P[1,1] = A[1]*B[1]
    S[1,1] = 1
    for k in range(2,m):
        P[1,k] = np.inf
    for i in range(2,n):
        P[i,0] = 0
        for k in range(1,m):
            P[i,k] = min (P[i-1,k], P[i-1,k-1] + B[i] * A[k])    
            if (P[i-1,k] > P[i-1,k-1] + B[i] * A[k]):
                A_[i,k] = A[k]
                B_[i,k] = B[i]
                S[i,k] = 1

    return P,A_,B_,S
```

```
A = np.array([0,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]) # -> Insert 1 dummy value at the first position
B = np.array([0,37.97, 34.45, 32.41, 32.17, 35.48, 35.91, 33.81, 32.23, 33.46,
       35.35, 33.03, 37.36, 32.18, 29.29, 30.23, 30.94, 34.26, 31.74,
       29.24, 25.93, 29.26, 33.64, 33.28]) # -> Insert 1 dummy value at the first position
m = len(A)
n = len(B)
mat,A_,B_,S = min_dot_product(A,B,m,n)
```

```
Out:
mat
array([[  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [  0.  , 241.15,    inf,    inf,    inf,    inf,    inf,    inf],
       [  0.  , 226.87, 435.61,    inf,    inf,    inf,    inf,    inf],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 419.89, 596.46,    inf,    inf,    inf,    inf],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 419.89, 596.46, 738.38,    inf,    inf,    inf],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 419.89, 596.46, 738.38, 846.11,    inf,    inf],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 419.89, 588.94, 731.7 , 839.81, 913.73,    inf],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 418.57, 581.04, 717.86, 828.39, 904.27, 945.96],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 418.57, 581.04, 714.88, 818.24, 895.31, 937.73],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 418.57, 581.04, 714.88, 818.24, 888.94, 930.66],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 418.57, 581.04, 713.16, 813.97, 884.3 , 921.97],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 418.57, 581.04, 713.16, 813.97, 884.3 , 921.66],
       [  0.  , 225.19, 418.27, 579.47, 709.76, 809.7 , 878.33, 916.48],
       [  0.  , 205.03, 400.93, 564.72, 696.63, 797.63, 868.28, 907.62],
       [  0.  , 205.03, 386.41, 552.08, 685.64, 787.32, 858.09, 898.51],
       [  0.  , 205.03, 386.41, 541.11, 675.84, 778.46, 849.2 , 889.03],
       [  0.  , 205.03, 386.41, 541.11, 675.84, 778.46, 846.98, 883.46],
       [  0.  , 205.03, 386.41, 541.11, 668.07, 771.06, 841.94, 878.72],
       [  0.  , 204.68, 380.47, 532.61, 658.07, 755.79, 829.54, 871.18],
       [  0.  , 181.51, 360.26, 510.12, 636.33, 735.86, 807.65, 855.47],
       [  0.  , 181.51, 357.07, 506.56, 627.16, 724.11, 794.38, 836.91],
       [  0.  , 181.51, 357.07, 506.56, 627.16, 724.11, 791.39, 828.02],
       [  0.  , 181.51, 357.07, 506.56, 627.16, 724.11, 790.67, 824.67]])

A_
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 7., 6., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 7., 6., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 5., 4., 3., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 1.]])

B_
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  , 32.41, 32.41,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  , 32.17, 32.17, 32.17,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 35.48,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 35.91,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 33.81, 33.81, 33.81, 33.81,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , 32.23, 32.23, 32.23, 32.23, 32.23, 32.23],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 33.46, 33.46, 33.46, 33.46],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 35.35, 35.35],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 33.03, 33.03, 33.03, 33.03],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 37.36],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , 32.18, 32.18, 32.18, 32.18, 32.18, 32.18],
       [ 0.  , 29.29, 29.29, 29.29, 29.29, 29.29, 29.29, 29.29],   x7
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , 30.23, 30.23, 30.23, 30.23, 30.23, 30.23],   x6
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 30.94, 30.94, 30.94, 30.94, 30.94],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 34.26, 34.26],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 31.74, 31.74, 31.74, 31.74],
       [ 0.  , 29.24, 29.24, 29.24, 29.24, 29.24, 29.24, 29.24],   x5
       [ 0.  , 25.93, 25.93, 25.93, 25.93, 25.93, 25.93, 25.93],   x4
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , 29.26, 29.26, 29.26, 29.26, 29.26, 29.26],   x3
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 33.64, 33.64],   x2
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 33.28, 33.28]])  x1
```

So min = P[n-1][m-1] = 824.67 = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]*[33.28,33.64,29.26,25.93,29.24,30.23,29.29]

To reverse A_ and B_:

```
def reverse(S,A_,B_):
    n,m = S.shape
    state = m-1
    pos = []
    if state >= 0:
        for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
            if (S[i][state] == 1):
                state = state - 1
                pos.append([i,state+1])

    new_B = np.zeros(B_.shape)
    new_A = np.zeros(A_.shape)
    for p in pos:
        new_B[p[0],p[1]] = B_[p[0],p[1]]
        new_A[p[0],p[1]] = A_[p[0],p[1]]

    return new_B,new_A
```

Comment: Are you looking for a subsequence of `B`, or could it be `37,97, 29.29, 33.28`?

Comment: Use dynamic programming. What have you tried?

Comment: a subsequence of 7 numbers from B

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo: I sorted B ascending, get first seven numbers, and sort the index ascending again so that I wont messed the order. However, the result I got wasn't the minimum...

Comment: I updated my answer. It should work

Comment: To clarify - do the elements of B that you choose need to be a contiguous subarray, or could they be a subsequence with gaps between items as long as they’re in the right order?

Comment: @templatetypedef I updated my question. They are allowed to have gaps in between

Comment: You have to reverse the final set of selected B values. Moreover, in this particular example, selected values are all at the end. You could test your programme with a different B set

Comment: @Damien: I updated my answer for the reverse part based on your comment

Comment: In practice you don't need to reverse these big matrices. Only reverse the array of optimal B values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you’re solving here has the following form:

> Given two sequences A and B of lengths m and n, along with a number k, find the subsequence of B of length m that has the lowest dot product with A.

In your original problem, we have m = 7, but more generally I’d imagine that seven could be replaced by any number.

This problem has a nice dynamic programming solution. The intuition behind it is the following. Suppose you pick some number out of the array B to serve as the first element of your m-element vector. You then have the task of determining what the remaining m-1 elements are going to be. If you think about it, you’d want to pick them so that the dot product of those m-1 elements with the last m-1 elements of A is as small as possible. So then, the questions become “how do you decide what that first item should be,” and “how you choose the follow-up items?”

One way to do this would be to use a recursive search. The idea goes something like this:

- If the length of B is equal to the length of A, you have no choice but to pick every element of B, in order.
- Otherwise, you have choices. One option would be to exclude the first element of B. If you do that, you have to pick m elements from the remaining elements of B such that you get the smallest dot product with A. The other option is to pick the first element of B, meaning that you’d want to pick m-1 elements from the rest of B with the goal of minimizing the dot product with the m-1 tail elements of A. So evaluate both options, then take whichever is better.

This approach will work, but as written it’ll be too slow to be practical. Fortunately, it happens to nicely convert to a dynamic programming solution. Notice that each recursive call can be framed as solving a problem of the following form:

> Given an index i into A and an index j into B, what’s the smallest dot product you can form of a subsequence of B starting at position j and the subvector of A starting at position i?

There are only O(mn) possible values that i and j can take on here, and so we can approach this problem as just filling in a table of that size. Specifically, let’s have T[i, j] be our table. We’d fill it in as follows:

- T[i, j] = 0 if i = m. That is, if we’re not allowed to use any elements of A, then the dot product will be an empty sum of zero.
- T[i, j] = infinity if n - j < m - i. That is, if we have fewer elements left in B than we have left in A, then we can’t even form a dot product, so we’ll just pretend the answer is “something so big you’d never pick it.”
- T[i, j] = min(T[i, j+1], A[i] * B[j] + T[i+1, j+1]) otherwise. That is, we have two choices: don’t include the jth element of B in our vector, in which case we have to find the elements to pick in the subarray of B starting at position j+1; or include the jth element of B, which will be multiplied by the ith element of A in the dot product, then minimize what’s left.

Filling in each table item takes time O(1), so we can populate the table in time O(mn). From there, we can use the standard DP table-walking algorithm to reconstruct the exact set of items to include. (We can actually speed this up by noticing that since we need a subsequence of B of length m that we don’t need to fill in the whole table because m<sup>2</sup> of the elements will be infinity, and we can skip filling them in. That gives a runtime of O(m(n - m + 1))).

Comment: I'm still not quite getting it, how can i get a dot product from A[i] * B[j] + T[i+1, j+1] ??

Comment: The idea is that A[i] * T[j] denotes the product of one element from A and another from B, and the T term represents “the product of the best choices of the remaining elements.”

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. How can I know the components of best choice? Like results = A[0]*B[10]+A[1]*B[24]..... and so on?

Comment: @HaAnTran This is a standard technique in dynamic programming, and I suspect that I'm probably not going to do the best job articulating it purely in this comment. Do a Google search for "recover solution dynamic programming" and you'll find some great references on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was rewritten in the answer of @templatetypedef:

"Given two sequences A and B of lengths m and n, find the subsequence of B of length m that has the lowest dot product with A."

The approach here is to consider a dynamic programming algorithm for finding the most likely sequence of hidden states, using a forward-backward procedure.

Here, a state at position `i` corresponds to the number of elements of `A` potentially used at this position, where `i` corresponds to the index in `B` array. The total number of possibilities can then be represented by a graph, the best solution corresponding to a path in this graph.

This method principly uses two arrays:

`P[i][k]`:   best (minimum) current dot product values by considering the first `i` values of `A`, assuming `k` values of `B` array have been used

`S[i][k]` memorization of the decision taken at step `i`, for each state `k`.
    `k`corresponds to the state of the underlying trellis.

**Forward iteration**: calculation of the path metrics

Initialization:

```
P[1][0] = 0             -> case B[1] is not used
P[1][1] = A[1]*B[1]     -> case B[1] is used
P[1][k] = infinite for k = 2..m
S[1][0] = 0
S[1][1] = 1
```

Recursive calculation of `P[i][k]`

```
Do i = 2 to n
    P[i][0] = 0
    S[i][0] = 0
    Do k = 1 to m
        P[i][k] = min (P[i-][k], P[i-1][k-1] + B[i] * A[k])
        S[i][k] = 0 in the first case       -> B[i] is not used
        S[i][k] = 1 in the second case      -> B[i] is used
```

Note that in the inner loop, you can set the maximum `k` value to `min(i, m)` instead of `m`, to save some useless computations.

**Backward iteration**: reading of the solution

```
Minimum dot product = P[n][m]
```

Corresponding best `A` values are obtained by going through the trellis in reverse order, starting from position `(n, m)`, and noting the `i` positions for which we have `S[i][state] = 1`. The optimal path in the graph corresponds to the successive values of `state`.

```
state = m;
Do i = n to 1
    if (S[i][state) == 1)
        state = state - 1
        B[i] (or index i) is added to the solution set S[]
    else
        state unchanged
```

At the end of the process, the array `S[]` contains the best sequence of the `B[i]`, in reverse order.

Global time and space complexity is O(nm).

This dynamic approach is similar to the one posted in the answer of @templatetypedef. The difference is that it was obtained by explicitely introducing hidden states, when it was implicit in the other approach.

Another difference is that we get a *loop* solution instead of a *recursive* one.

Comment: How can I know the components of best choice? Like P[n][m]
= A[0]*B[10]+A[1]*B[24]..... and so on

Comment: I completed the post: the array `S[]` contains the best selection of the `B[i]`, in reverse order. I also corrected some typos, there was a confusion between arrays  `A` and `B` in the previous version. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There you go. Edit: sorry, just saw that you want an algorithm. If it matters at all, it doesn't take long to run it. With arrays of length 1,000 and 1,000,000, it took 1.57 seconds. It has linear complexity, I don't see why the use of an algorithm would be warranted.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
B = np.array([37.97, 34.45, 32.41, 32.17, 35.48, 35.91, 33.81, 32.23, 33.46,
       35.35, 33.03, 37.36, 32.18, 29.29, 30.23, 30.94, 34.26, 31.74,
       29.24, 25.93, 29.26, 33.64, 33.28])

def return_smallest(short, long):
   f = list()
   len_small = short.shape[0]
   len_long = long.shape[0]
   for x in [long[i:i+len_small] for i in range(0, len_long-len_small)]:
      f.append(np.dot(short, x))
   i = np.argmin(f)
   return long[i:i+len_small]

return_smallest(A, B)
```

`Out[1]: array([29.29, 30.23, 30.94, 34.26, 31.74, 29.24, 25.93])`

Comment: I suspect this won’t be very fast for, say, A having length 1,000 and B having length 1,000,000 because many of the recursive calls will be duplicated and the cost of the slices will be large. Using DP will really speed this up.

Comment: I did it, and it's 1.57 seconds with my laptop. It's linear complexity, that's nothing.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you’re doing, but it looks like you’re looking at all contiguous subarrays of the longer sequence. I was under the impression that the OP’s question was about *subsequences* of the longer sequence, which aren’t required to be contiguous. But perhaps I’m misinterpreting either your code or the original question?

Comment: Good question, I think he means contiguous since he wrote 'without changing the order' but yes, it's not completely clear to me.

Comment: 'The order of both arrays must not be changed'

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais : Sorry if my question is not clear. By not changing the order, I mean if I choose element at index 2, the next one could be index 5 or 10 but not at index 0 or 1. They dont need to be consecutive like index 2,3,4,5....